# jquery cannot fire event when select item from the listbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I learned example from [ASP.NET MVC Listbox handling selected item events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519433/asp-net-mvc-listbox-handling-selected-item-events)

I tried my code like this example, but I spent almost 3 hours to figure out why a event was not fired when selecting an item from the list in MVC 4 razor. I dont know why i cant solve this problem. Please look at my code what have i done wrong. Your help means alot.

I need to get event fired and pass value to Action parameter (id).

Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        viewModels.ViewCars = repository.GetCars();


        var lstCars = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (Car car in viewModels.ViewCars)
        {
            var carItem = new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = car.Description,
                Value = car.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
            };
            lstCars.Add(carItem);
        }

        viewModels.ListCarItems = lstCars;


        return View(viewModels);

    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int id)
    {
   List<CarData> data = repository.GetCarData();

        CarData car = data.Single(m => m.Id == id);

        viewModels.CarDetails = car;

        return View(viewModels);
    }
```

View:

```
@model ConsoleMVC.Models.ViewModels

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

  @Html.ListBox("carId", Model.ListCarItems)
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#carId').change(function () {
        alert("PING!"); //Not fire event, why?
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Index","Home")',
            data: JSON.stringify({ id: $('#carId').val()}),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = data.Url;
            } 
        });
    });

  });
</script>
```

**UPDATE:**

~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link href="~/Content/screen.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/CarSite.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <header class="header">

</header>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="content">
            <div id="body">
                @RenderSection("featured", required: false)
                <section style="padding: 20px;">
                    @RenderBody()
                </section>
            </div>
        </div><!-- .content -->
        <footer class="footer">

        </footer><!-- .footer -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: maybe wrap your js in `$(document).ready(function(){...})`

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#carId').change(function () {
        alert("PING!"); 

        ...
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your select has been dynamically added to the DOM, try to use event delegation here:

```
$(document).on('change', '#carId', function() {
    // Your code here 
});
```

If not, then make sure that you've included jQuery properly, put your jQuery code after loaded `jQuery` and your select id is `carId`.

Comment: not working :( Yes i put jquery code after loaded. u think html.listbox may have something wrong?